# loading framework7 inside android webview app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, html-framework-7

i've downloaded f7 single view template 
https://github.com/framework7io/framework7-template-single-view

and created an android webview app to load the web inside the app ... but it wont show up 
it shows any other web app fine ... just not f7 apps 
obviously there is something missing here ... i should do something to load f7 inside android webview 
anyone has done this before ? am i missing something ?

btw im not using cordova or any other lib ... just a simple webview ... here is my MainActivity.js .. im using api 16

```
package com.zarinbet.zarinb;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public WebView webview ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.MainWebView);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webview.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);

        webview.loadUrl("http://10.0.2.2/framework7/");



    }
}
```

my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.zarinbet.zarinb">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.zarinbet.zarinb.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/MainWebView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: http://10.0.2.2/framework7/ check this link in browser. framework7 is not working i guess.

Comment: @prasannaputtaswamy that address is my localhost for android simulator  ... it works fine on the web

Comment: this is the url you are loading 'http://10.0.2.2/framework7/'  which wont work as you mentioned that ip is simulator ip not system ip instead of ip place localhost there or use your system ip. that will work for sure